# Problem with permissions to my hard disk

Tags: permissions, hard-disk

I plugged in another hard disk that I want it to use as a backup hard disk

when I do:

```
 fdisk -l
```

I get:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt


Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 976773134 976771087 465.8G Linux filesystem
```

So I wanted to format the hard disk that it will suit to windows also so I installed the package `dosfstools` and run:

```
mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1
```

Now I mounted the hard disk to: `/home/backup` via the command:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /home/backup
```

now when I'm doing `ls -l` in `home` directory I see:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 32768 Jan  1  1970 backup
```

I try to give it permissions:

```
chmod -R -v 777 backup
```

and I get:

> mode of 'backup' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)

But when I do `ls -l` it still have the same permissions (rwxr-xr-x)

What is the problem? why it dosen't changed ?
Also I wanted to know if it's right what I did with the format to make it work on windows also...?

Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick I already try it, when I run `sudo chattr -i file` I get `chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on backup`

Comment: The directory isn't immutable, it just doesn't support the file permissions concept. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT32 does not support per-file and per-directory permissions in the UNIX sense. The permissions are set based on the mounting of the drive.

See: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37072/linux-fat32-and-etc-fstab), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118199/how-do-i-change-file-permissions-on-a-fat32-drive) and [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/79813/read-and-write-permission-for-fat32-partition-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Hey thanks , I did `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/backup -o dmask=000,fmask=111` and it works, I will accept your answer in a few minutes, but I can't up vote it because I don't have the reputation , sorry

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.